# How to install mysql on a new machine for an old app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, geocode

Not exactly sure how to go about this.

My app's `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: application-dev
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: angles123
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I was thinking that it would be wise to go ahead and `mysqladmin -u root --password=angles123`, and then once inside `create database application-dev`, but the `-dev` part, mysql is not happy about. But Icould create a database that said simply `application`.

Am I missing someting else possibly?

The reason I am bringing this up is because I get this error whenever I try to rake db:migrate, or script/server

```
rake db:test:prepare
(in /Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Geocode
```

So I assumed I set up the database wrong because I clearly have that gem installed.

Here is the full stacktrace :

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Geocode
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing_not_from_s3_library'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/config/initializers/geocode.rb:1
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/config/environment.rb:21
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/macuser/Sites/hq_channel/vendor/rails/railties/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Comment: i bet geocode is missing a library

Comment: @sam, I tried reinstalling geocode, but its not included in my config file. Geokit is though. And neither is actually used in my application, which makes me think is it possible to remove its dependencies on it? How would you go bout fixing a missing library?

Comment: specifically for for Geokit I don't know. But for some gems you need to give the path do the library. You do that by :lib => 'path/to/lib'

Comment: such as config.gem 'geokit', :lib => 'path/to/geokit'

Comment: @sam, what would the root of that path be? from application I have, `gems/geokit-1.4.1/lib/geokit`

Comment: @trip, I honestly don't know the full story but for two of my gems I need to include a lib. they are :  `config.gem "ultraviolet", :lib => 'uv'`, and  `config.gem "aws-s3", :lib => "aws/s3"`

Comment: If you're not using it, remove `/config/initializers/geocode.rb` since it's initializing Geocode.

Answer (score 0):

I've had mysql installations that didn't allow underscores or dashes in the database names.

You could try changing the database name to `application` and then running `rake db:create` to see if it creates your database.

Also, you can try running rake with `--trace` to get a better idea of what's being included from where that's causing that error.

Comment: Hey I think you're right. I got this when I tried `rake db:create
(in /Users/macuser/Sites/application)
Couldn't create database for {"reconnect"=>false, "encoding"=>"utf8", "username"=>"rootsies", "adapter"=>"mysql", "database"=>"application", "pool"=>5, "password"=>"angles1234", "socket"=>"/tmp/mysql.sock"}, charset: utf8, collation: utf8_general_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation)`

Comment: I have also, set priveleges for root and my user for the database as well. What do you think I missing?

Comment: Sounds like a database connection or permissions issue.  Maybe you don't have CREATE permissions for your non-root user?

Comment: Got the rake db:create to work by simply updating my LoadModules in apache. It seems those needed to be upgraded for a 64 bit computer to be able to process it. And I did the arch flags for mysql. When I run rake db:create it says it already exists now. So that works. But I still get the original geocode error if I do `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:test:prepare` or `script/server`

Comment: *blink* Updating Apache fixed mysql?  Woah.  Try removing that initializer (/config/initializers/geocode.rb) since running rake loads up your app, including environment and initializers.

Comment: Clever! Well that definately got me through a majority of the migrations but it looks like its actually used somewhere with a `acts_as_geocodable` method in a few spots. So I'm going to put it back. :D

Comment: Sounds like you're back to getting Geocode/Geokit working as the root fix.